# Single readstream to multiple writestream with different types of processing and dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

How do I create multiple writestreams of different dataframes for eventhubs from one readstream from eventhub?

I checked one read-stream with one write stream and one read-stream with multiple write streams for the same dataset:

```
    dataframe = spark.readstream.format("eventhubs") --> From Eventhub 1
    dataframe = Process1(dataframe)
    dataframe = Process2(dataframe)
    dataframe.writestream.format(eventhub).forbatchwriter(eventhub2)  --> Eventhub 2

    Process1(dataframe)
    {
     records:dataset[test] = dataframe.filter("xx = 10")
     finalRecords:dataframe = records.transform()
     finalRecords.writestream.format(eventhubs).forbatchwriter(eventhub3)
    }

    Process2(dataframe)
    {
     records:dataset[test] = dataframe.filter("xx = 30")
     finalRecords:dataframe = records.transform()
     finalRecords.writestream.format(eventhubs).forbatchwriter(eventhub3)   ---> Eventhub 4
    }
```

In the above scenario, process 1 and process 2 are getting distinct events and sometimes eventhub times out because of a race condition with one readstream.

How can I do the above processing from a single read from eventhub.

Comment: I will be pulling the data from eventhub and pushing to event hubs after filtering. what do you mean by streaming queries ? I am doing the processing-filter in two different processors

Comment: `spark.readstream` creates a streaming query. How do you execute the code? Do you use `spark-submit` or something similar?